# How to remove dynamic content HTTP_URIs(Ask from Power App) from Power App Flow

Tags: powerapps

How to delete this dynamic content in my Power App Flow?

[image]

When I run flow, it requires to pass HTTP_URI. I want to delete them, but I cannot find where to do that in Power App Flow.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found that maybe one of the solutions that can solve this problem is to delete the entire Power App trigger action and recreate it.

Last comment on "Removing dynamic content" topic:
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Removing-dynamic-content/td-p/16386

Comment: Don't forget to remove the Flow from the PowerApp (View/DataSources) then save and publish the app. Then re-add the Flow once the trigger has been changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove from flow the init action "PowerApps" and use "PowerApps (V2)" instead. Then you create input params manually.

Another work around is to remove the trigger for PowerApps. This however will remove all variables so you would need to restore them. But in some cases this can work.

Comment: Thank you @Dustin, I removed trigger and reset variables again and it worked for me!